# Fix the camera while walking unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently when I walk the camera follows the player even when he turns sideways, I wanted the X axis to be kept, so that only the camera walks, doesn't move sideways, I'm trying:

```
        Camera.main.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 8, -10);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(40,0,0);
        Camera.main.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

Comment: Could you add Abit more details? Currently it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the camera as child of the player GameObject? If that’s the case, you should not do this. It will always rotate the camera with the player object.